# I'm not able to install scribus in my Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I'm new to Ubuntu. I entered in Terminal the following lines:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:scribus/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install scribus-ng
```

The first two codes are working but in the case of the third statement the result it's like this:

```
sudo apt install scribus-ng
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmetacity-private3a : Depends: metacity-common (= 1:3.18.7-0ubuntu0.3) but 1:3.18.7-0ubuntu0.2 is to be installed
 scribus-ng : Depends: python-tk but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: scribus-ng-data (= 1.5.2-0ubuntu16.04.0~ppa0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libgraphicsmagick-q16-3 (>= 1.3.5) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libopenscenegraph100v5 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libpodofo0.9.3 but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: fonts-dejavu but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: icc-profiles-free but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I'm getting this error. How can I overcome it?

Comment: Did you try running `apt-get -f install`?

Comment: Is there any reason to have the latest version of scribus (1.5.2, I suppose)? The default Ubuntu repositories support scribus 1.4.6 for Xenial (16.04). If this would be OK for you, just remove  the ppa from your installation sources and install scribus.

Comment: yeah i tried with`apt-get -f install ` . even that is not working..

Comment: Even by removing ppa .. I'm not able to install..